# JQuery Mobile skip specific element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to tell jquery mobile to skip a specific element?

I have a custom div that looks like:

```
<div class="fr-confRoomInfo">
<a href="#" class="fr-confRoomBtn blue ui-link">
<span>Some text</span></a>
</div>
```

I dont want to apply the ui-link to the  tag in that specific div. Is there any way to do that?

**EDIT**
I ended up moving my custom css link below the jquery mobile so I could just override the css parameters that I needed to change. So in my css i ended up doing this:

```
.fr-confRoomInfo
{
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Which got rid of the text-shadow that was actually inherited from ui-body-c (not ui-link)

Comment: Which tag? What do you mean by `apply the ui-link`?

Comment: jquery mobile automatically applies ui-link to any <a> tag. I dont want it to. the fr-confRoomBtn and blue are my own custom css definitions

Answer (score 8):

**data-role="none"** is the right thing to tell jQuery Mobile to ignore your tag

Comment: Perfect answer - don't know why this hasn't been accepted yet!

Answer (score 1):

You could try `.not()`:

```
$('a').not('.fr-confRoomInfo > a').addClass('ui-link');
```

or you could just add it to everything, and remove it from the one you want excluded:

```
$('a').addClass('ui-link');
$('.fr-confRoomInfo > a').removeClass('ui-link');
```

**EDIT** given your comment about `ui-link` always being added, just try the last line of the second snippet above.

Comment: I ended up just moving my custom css file below the jquery mobile css file and then overriding the style. Thank for your solution though.